# Atmosphere 2.0+ and Spring Security Sessions

Tags: java, spring, gwt, spring-security, atmosphere

There are a lot questions about working with Atmosphere + Spring Security but no answers. Is it possible to use Atmosphere 2.0+ with Spring Security? 
Or at least in parallel without conflict. Because atmosphere invalidate spring security session.

And it would be great to find example Atmospehere 2.0+ with Spring Security and GWT.

I use Java8, Tomcat8, Spring Security 3.1.2, GWT 2.6.1 (GWT-SL for working with Spring Security). And I would like to integrate Atmosphere 2.2.+. In Dev mode for GWT as always Jetty. For now I cannot up solution in dev mode.
Any fresh ideas or solutions please.

If somebody has good expirience with another websocet/comet framework with GWT please post too. I'm ready to go on similar technology. What about Spring Framework 4.0 M2: WebSocket Messaging and GWT?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use Spring Security and many users have described how they do it. If you post your question on the Atmosphere mailing list with the exact problems you are facing, I'm sure people will show you how to.

-- Jeanfrancois

Comment: Thank you @jfarcand for the answer. This is my post with more details [here](http://atmosphere-users-mailling-list.2493822.n2.nabble.com/Atmosphere-with-Spring-Security-for-GWT-app-td7577557.html).  Please answer because I spent on this more then week. I am in despair. Thank you again

Comment: Hi @jfarcand. Please find my post [Here](http://alex.66705.x6.nabble.com/Atmosphere-with-Spring-Security-for-GWT-app-td2.html). It is clarified. Please help because I cannot solve the issue more then week. Thank you in advance